# ERROR LNK2019:EXE using DLL with multiple headers and Sources for a Main Class composed of other classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll

I was trying to build  "AccountDllTest.cpp" to test the dll "Account.dll" in Visual Studio 2013 but continuously getting  this Linker Error ..

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: AccountDllTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
    1>AccountDllTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Date::Date(int,int,int)" (??0Date@@QEAA@HHH@Z) referenced in function main
    1>AccountDllTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Date::getMonth(void)" (?getMonth@Date@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main
    1>C:\Users\Soumyadeep\Documents\Projects\AccountDllTest\x64\Debug\AccountDllTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The "Account.dll" was also successfully built with Visual Studio 2013 with the following files

1. Interface.h
2. Account.h
3. Date.h
4. Time.h
5. Account.cpp
6. Date.cpp
7. Time.cpp

Here the "**Interface.h**" just defines the abstract class "**IAccount**" containing pure virtual functions and the "**Account.h**" defines the "**Account**" Class derived from the "**IAccount**" class. The "**IAccount**" and "**Account**" classes are composed of objects of "**Date**" and "**Time**" classes defined and implemented in "**Date.h**","**Date.cpp**","**Time.h**","**Time.cpp**" respectively.

The code of AccountDllTest.cpp is given below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include"Headers\Interface.h"
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

typedef IAccount* (_cdecl *FactoryFunc)();
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE dll_handle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("..\\Core\\Account.dll"));
    if (!dll_handle)
    {
        cout << "\n Unable to load Dll!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n Dll successfully loaded!!" << endl;
    }

    FactoryFunc Create = (FactoryFunc)GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "createAccount");
    IAccount* AC_1 = Create();
    AC_1->setAccountNo(1);
    AC_1->credit(2300);
    cout << "\n Balance after credit" << AC_1->getBalance() << endl;
    AC_1->lockAccount();
    AC_1->credit(2300);
    Date a;
    a = AC_1->getLockDate();
    cout<<"The account was locked on " ;
    a.print();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The code was running without hiccups before I decided to test the Date objects after this line

```
 AC_1->credit(2300);
```

What am I missing?
Sorry for this long question, but would really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes from your dll (as I see this is the Date class), first of all such classes must be imported with __declspec dllimport and secondly you have to link your test program with your dll library (yourdll.lib) to resolve external symbols:

```
AccountDllTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Date::Date(int,int,int)" (??0Date@@QEAA@HHH@Z) referenced in function main
AccountDllTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Date::getMonth(void)" (?getMonth@Date@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main
```

Try to read about dllimport and dllexport here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx

Comment: Do i need to link to .lib files even if I use Explicit Linking?? BTW, the code was running without linking to .lib file until the use of the Date object "a".

Comment: If you plan to use classes with implementation from your dll, you have to import such classes and link with library.

Comment: But I am using a factory function to return an Object of that Account class to use the functionalities of the class and it is only the Factory Function that is to be exported . I have been using this method successfully in my previous projects.. only this time I tried to use a class object composed of other class objects.. and failed.

Comment: The diffrence between Explicit Linking and Implicit Linking can be found from these links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/784bt7z7.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must reference the DLL from your project.
To do this, simply:

1. In Solutions Explorer, click on your project and then, on the menu bar, click "Project" and next "References.
2. In "Common Properties", click "Framework and references" and next "Add new reference"
3. On the "Projects" tab, select your dll-project and click "OK".

Also you need to modify the includes directory path.

1. In Solutions Explorer, right click on your project and click "Properties"
2. In "C/C++" node (under "Configuration Properties"), select "General"
3. In "Additional Include Directories", add the path of the location of the headers (.h) of your DLL and click "OK"

You can read the official documentation for creating ad using a DLL.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Note that you have to add the defines on your header:
    #ifdef YOURHEADER_EXPORTS
    #define YOURHEADER_API __declspec(dllexport) 
    #else
    #define YOURHEADER_API __declspec(dllimport) 
    #endif

Comment: I dont want to use Account.dll project . What if the Account.dll is a third party one??

Comment: Go to Solution Explorer > Right click on your project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker and:
In "general" add the path of DLL to "additional library directories";
In "input" add the name of DLL (extension too) to "additional dependencies"